# SQL query dropping needed rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this query.  it creates a calendar to use to compare to and from DOS on medical claims to count the distinct # of days.

When I run it, I seem to drop a few rows that dont show up in my results.

can anyone see why these rows would not be counted in this query?

```
ICN From Date of Service To Date of Service Detail Status Code
12345 20121102 12:00:00 20121103 12:00:00 P
12345 20121102 12:00:00 20121103 12:00:00 P
12345 20121102 12:00:00 20121103 12:00:00 P
12345 20121102 12:00:00 20121103 12:00:00 D
12345 20121102 12:00:00 20121103 12:00:00 D
12345 20121102 12:00:00 20121103 12:00:00 D
12345 20121102 12:00:00 20121103 12:00:00 D
12345 20121102 12:00:00 20121103 12:00:00 D
```

```
CREATE TABLE #Calendar1(Dt DATETIME NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT CAST('20120101' AS DATETIME) AS c 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(dd,1,c) FROM cte 
    WHERE c < '20131231'
)
INSERT INTO #Calendar1 SELECT c FROM cte OPTION  (MAXRECURSION 1);


SELECT
    ICN,
    COUNT(DISTINCT Dt) AS Days
FROM
    AllOPBYDOS s
    INNER JOIN #Calendar1 c ON
        s.[from Date of service] >= c.Dt AND s.[to Date of service] < c.Dt+1
--Where [Detail Status Code] = 'p'

GROUP BY
    ICN;
```

Answer (score 0):

When I run the calendar query on SQL Server 2008, it only produces one row.  I think you want:

```
INSERT INTO #Calendar1 SELECT c FROM cte OPTION  (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

For the rows that are dropped, are you sure they have dates in the range in the calendar?  You should probably do a left outer join and check for the extremes:

```
SELECT ICN, COUNT(DISTINCT Dt) AS Days,
       sum(case when [from Date of service] not between const.mindt and const.maxdt or
                     [to Date of service] not between const.mindt and const.maxdt
                then 1
                else 0
           end) as OutOfRangeRecords
FROM AllOPBYDOS s left outer JOIN
     #Calendar1 c
     ON s.[from Date of service] >= c.Dt AND s.[to Date of service] < c.Dt+1 cross join
     (select MAX(dt) as maxdt, MIN(dt) as mindt from #Calendar1) const
GROUP BY ICN;
```

Comment: the problem is, I need distinct days.  the example above is very easy to figure out.  There could also be overlapping days as well.ICN FROM DATE OF SERVICE TO DATE OF SERVICE PAID STATUS
12345 1/1/2013 1/5/2013 P
12345 1/8/2013 1/10/2013 p
12345 1/2/2013 1/7/2013 p
12345 1/9/2013 1/15/2013 p
12345 1/8/2013 1/15/2013 p

The total days in this icn would be 15. but as you can see, there are overlapping days, and a mixture of dates in the from and to dates of service.

Comment: I accidentally changed the max recursion to 1.  I changed it back to 0.  when I run this query against my table, I miss 29 ICNS.  the example above is an example of an icn that was not included in my results and I cant figure out why.  im guessing its the inner join, but i dont know why

Comment: If you want to preserve all calendar dates and detect which dates have no data, you should do a right-join to the #Calendar1 table.

Comment: I changed the inner, to a right join and i still get the same amount of results.  Im still missing 29 ICNS

Comment: @Ray . . . was thinking "cross join" but wrote "left outer join".  Oops.

Comment: no worries I Appreciate your time.  When I run that query just for the icns that were missing originally,  it calculated the days as 0. But all of the out of range records show up as 0's, there are no 1's

Comment: @Ray . . . Glad I could be of help.

Comment: the problem is, why didnt these records show up in the query, and the second question is why did they show up as 0 days in your query when it should have show up having 1 or more?

Comment: another thing I noticed is that If I change the date in the cast statement to 20110101, it adds 10 more records with 0 days.

Comment: @gordon   is there some type of issue with the date logic?

Comment: @Ray . . . The logic for your queries are probably ok.  You need to investigate the data itself.

Comment: @gordon.    The data is no different than any other.  it is all imported via a text file from a BO query. I cant see why the icns would not show up in either table for my original inner join to work, or why it shows up as 0 days when I run your query.